# Should i use different instances of a single ActionListener for multiple buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a single ActionListener for multiple buttons:

```
private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource().equals(button1)) {
                // do something
            } else if (event.getSource().equals(button2)) {
                // do something else
            }
        }
}
```

Which one of the following is the better way to add the ActionListener to these buttons and why?

1.:

```
button1.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
button2.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

2.:

```
MyActionListener mal = new MyActionListener();

button1.addActionListener(mal);
button2.addActionListener(mal);
```

I went with the 2nd option, but not sure it's the proper way.

Comment: The second choice would be definitely faster, but I think the speed difference is so small it doesn't really matter in this case. If you need a more flexible choice then choice option 1, with parameters, is what I'd go with. If your buttons are doing the exact same thing then I'd go with option 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question asks for opinion and may be closed, and because of this, I'm answering as a community wiki, but I think the best answer is "it depends".

What I do is if all listeners are exactly the same, and you're not passing anything different into each constructor, then just have each button share the same listener. If I need to pass unique information into the listeners, then I use separate listeners, but really either will work, and neither will likely cause an appreciable difference in program operation or responsiveness.